# NullReferenceException on DataRow.Delete() when row exists

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

This problem is driving me nuts.  I've re-written the code about three times, and the error is the same every time.  In a dataset, I am trying to remove any parent rows that do not have child rows.  The code is simply this (iterating in reverse so the column collection can be modified):

```
' This block causes the error.  Commenting out does not cause the error
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Search.Text) Then
    For i As Integer = ds.Tables("Child").Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ds.Tables("Child").Rows(i).Item("RowValue").ToString().IndexOf(txt_Search.Text.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = -1 Then
            ds.Tables("Child").Rows(i).Delete()
        End If
    Next
End If

ds.AcceptChanges()

' Remove parent rows where no child rows are found
For i As Integer = ds.Tables("Parent").Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables("Child"))
    dv.RowFilter = String.Format("ID={0}", ds.Tables("Parent").Rows(i).Item("ID").ToString())
    If dv.ToTable().Rows.Count = 0 Then ' no child rows, remove parent
        Dim dtP As DataTable = ds.Tables("Parent")
        Dim drP As DataRow = dtP.Rows(i)
        If drP IsNot Nothing Then
            drP.Delete() ' <--  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I don't understand how this error can occur when (according to the debugger) both the table and row exist (there are 20 rows in the table).  I've done this type of thing many times before, but cannot figure this one out (been staring at it all day, so probably something really simple...)

Can anyone offer any suggestions please as to something I might even be able to try?

I even changed the code to this, and it *still* throws the same exception, which I really don't follow:

```
If ds.Tables("Parent").Rows(i) IsNot Nothing Then
    ds.Tables("Parent").Rows.RemoveAt(i) ' <--  Same outcome
End If
```

### Progress

Exception is thrown on the line shown.  The InnerException is Nothing.

However, checking out the variables prior to deletion, I see this which I don't know is relevant:

[image: Debug]

I see on MDSN that this exception occurs if a row with RowState of Deleted is deleted again.  However, AcceptChanges is called just before the block, so I don't see why the RowState is deleted...

In desperation, I also tried this, but again the error persists:

```
If drP IsNot Nothing AndAlso drP.RowState <> DataRowState.Deleted Then
    drP.Delete() ' <--  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
End If
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious error here. I can suggest to use a foreach loop over the rows of the parent table and when you find an empty child just call Delete on the row (this will not trigger the exception for a collection being modified), then outside the loop just call AcceptChanges to commit the deletions.

Comment: I cant repro either. I might use the DefaultView rather than a new DataView.  You could also use Linq though it would not be simpler - just allow you to create a seperate collection of rows to delete.

Comment: *Which* object reference is not set to an instance of an object? Is it `ds`, `ds.Tables("Parent")`, or `ds.Tables("Parent").Rows`?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace to show where the NRE is being thrown.  Side note - That seems like a convoluted way to get a child row count.  What's wrong with [DataRow.GetChildRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.getchildrows(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: The good Dr may not actually be using Data Relations or Foreign Keys, @TnTinMn

Comment: Thanks all for commenting.  There's another exception in there, but its not part of the main one.  I've posted more details in the updated question.  There are no DataRelations in the DataSet

Comment: I've also swapped out all RemoveAt methods for Delete

Comment: This appears strange to me.  In the image, the watch window shows the table as being named "Groups".  In that same image, the code statement is `Dim dtP As DataTable = ds.Tables("Parent")`.  Note: `ds.Tables("Nonexistant Name")` will return null.  Could it be that the debugger is showing the wrong line for the NRE and that dtP is actually null in `Dim drP As DataRow = dtP.Rows(i)`